# Mineral Extractors and Tanks, are they consumed?

Tags: astroneer

In Astroneer, I haven't used the mineral extractor yet and I don't know if it will consume the tank to become the material, so can anybody tell me if it will?

Answer (score 2):

No it won't consume the canister but extract the resources from it.

See the official wiki article on [**Mineral Extractor**](https://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Mineral_Extractor) for more Details.